# How to enable AOF in Redis on Windows?

Tags: php, redis

How to enable AOF in Redis on Windows?

I would like to write data to disk so that once the server reboots again use it.

In .php file I tried:

```
$redis->bgRewriteAOF();
```

In redis-cli.exe:

```
BGREWRITEAOF
```

and next:

```
SAVE
```

But if I reboot server, then data are lost.

In cli:

```
info persistence
```

return me:

```
aof_enabled:0
```

Answer (score 0):

In File : `redis.conf` Change

```
appendonly no
```

to

```
appendonly yes
```